# How to end the line on c++ using loops

Tags: c++

How do I end this loop and go to the next line? I want the loop to produce horizontally and then I want to be able to move on to the next line, but if I put "endl;" after my cout statement in the loop, it outputs the numbers vertically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int WMAX = 45,
    WMIN = 5;
    int wind;
    wind= WMIN;


    cout<< "Temp | -------------- Wind Speed --------------" <<endl;

    while (wind>=WMIN && wind<=WMAX) {
        cout<< setw(10) << wind << setw(5) << endl;
        wind+=5;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, *after* control leaves the loop, you want the cursor (the "print head", if you will) to advance to the next line. You observe that if you put `cout << endl;` *inside* the loop, it will execute after every number, whereas you want it to execute only *after* the loop has terminated. Can you think of *anyplace else* you might put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you would do is add a new line just outside the loop, something like this:

```
while(...) {
    ...
}

cout << endl;
```

This works just fine. Another way would be to have the line

```
cout << '\n' << flush;
```

which does just about the same thing.

Comment: So glad I was able to help.